# GIT bare with a remote SVN reference. How I update?

Tags: git, svn, fetch, git-bare

I have a bare git repository with a remote reference to a SVN repository.
Also I have a cloned repository from this.
I want to have this bare repository always synchronised, I'm doing a `git svn fetch`, but when I execute a `git log` I can not see the recently updated changes.
The idea is has a local branch in my local repository connected to the master of this bare repository and perform a `git pull` to bring the new changes.

Does somebody know how is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

`git svn fetch` doesn't update `master`. It looks like one needs to do that manually. I do that like this

```
git svn fetch
git branch -m master master2
git branch --track master refs/remotes/trunk
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master
git branch -d master2
```